# Docker : Worker keep exiting and respawn and 99% CPU

Tags: laravel, docker, redis, supervisord

Supervisord can't keep redis worker on, my worker still exited with satus code 12 and respawn. My redis container is on and on the the docker network of app (where supervisor be)

I follow the doc of laravel : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration

I tried to daemonize the command and some code update
I updated my Debian to Stretch and Docker as well
I tested all of it in local, everything works fine...

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=8
priority=10
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/worker.log
```

```
api:
    image: gitlab.ladechetterieduweb.com:5555/lddw/backend:latest
    container_name: backend-lddw-develop
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./config/api:/var/env
      - ./app/storage:/var/www/storage
      - ./logs/laravel:/var/www/storage/logs
      - ./logs/supervisord:/var/log
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: /bin/bash -c "cp /var/env/.env /var/www/.env && supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf --nodaemon"
    networks:
      - app-network

redis:
    image: redis:5.0.3-stretch
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    container_name: redis-lddw-develop
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
      - ./config/redis:/usr/local/etc/redis
    command: /bin/bash -c "cp /usr/local/etc/redis/rc.local /etc/rc.local && redis-server --appendonly yes"
    networks:
      - app-network
```

```
2019-06-25 21:50:15,199 CRIT Set uid to user 0
2019-06-25 21:50:15,199 WARN No file matches via include "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf"
2019-06-25 21:50:15,295 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2019-06-25 21:50:15,295 CRIT Server 'inet_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2019-06-25 21:50:15,457 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2019-06-25 21:50:15,457 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2019-06-25 21:50:15,457 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2019-06-25 21:50:16,460 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 10
2019-06-25 21:50:16,461 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_00' with pid 11
2019-06-25 21:50:16,463 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_01' with pid 12
2019-06-25 21:50:16,464 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_02' with pid 13
2019-06-25 21:50:16,467 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_03' with pid 14
2019-06-25 21:50:16,469 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_04' with pid 15
2019-06-25 21:50:16,472 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_05' with pid 16
2019-06-25 21:50:16,474 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_06' with pid 17
2019-06-25 21:50:16,476 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_07' with pid 18
2019-06-25 21:50:17,667 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-06-25 21:50:17,667 INFO success: laravel-worker_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-06-25 21:50:17,667 INFO success: laravel-worker_01 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-06-25 21:50:17,667 INFO success: laravel-worker_02 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-06-25 21:50:17,667 INFO success: laravel-worker_03 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-06-25 21:50:17,668 INFO success: laravel-worker_04 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-06-25 21:50:17,668 INFO success: laravel-worker_05 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-06-25 21:50:17,668 INFO success: laravel-worker_06 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-06-25 21:50:17,668 INFO success: laravel-worker_07 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-06-25 21:50:26,205 INFO exited: laravel-worker_00 (exit status 12; not expected)
2019-06-25 21:50:26,205 INFO exited: laravel-worker_02 (exit status 12; not expected)
2019-06-25 21:50:26,205 INFO exited: laravel-worker_03 (exit status 12; not expected)
2019-06-25 21:50:26,205 INFO exited: laravel-worker_05 (exit status 12; not expected)
2019-06-25 21:50:26,205 INFO exited: laravel-worker_06 (exit status 12; not expected)
2019-06-25 21:50:26,205 INFO exited: laravel-worker_07 (exit status 12; not expected)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your workers are exiting with status 12 :

```
2019-06-25 21:50:26,205 INFO exited: laravel-worker_00 (exit status 12; not expected)
2019-06-25 21:50:26,205 INFO exited: laravel-worker_02 (exit status 12; not expected)
2019-06-25 21:50:26,205 INFO exited: laravel-worker_03 (exit status 12; not expected)
2019-06-25 21:50:26,205 INFO exited: laravel-worker_05 (exit status 12; not expected)
2019-06-25 21:50:26,205 INFO exited: laravel-worker_06 (exit status 12; not expected)
2019-06-25 21:50:26,205 INFO exited: laravel-worker_07 (exit status 12; not expected)
```

This exit code is triggered when your worker is consuming too much memory, see :
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php#L204

**$this->memoryExceeded($options->memory)** returns true and exit.

You have 2 options, reducing the memory footprint of your worker or increasing memory allowed to it. As the default is pretty low (128MB), you can try to add some memory.

To change memory allowed to your workers, you have to edit your supervisord configuration :

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=3 --memory=1024
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=8
priority=10
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/worker.log
```

See the --memory I added to your conf in the command section

Regards

Comment: That's rock as hell ! Thx xalo